# Mockito 5.x.x fails Junit tests due to mock interaction inside log method

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, spring-test

After upgrading to Mockito 5.x.x, test cases started failing showing interactions on mocks, mentioned inside log message.

Prior to Mockito 5.x.x, the below code was working fine.

```java
  @Test
  void name() {
    Thread mockThread = Mockito.mock(Thread.class);
    logger.info("name ={}", mockThread.getName() );   //org.slf4j.Logger

    mockThread.start();

    Mockito.verify(mockThread).start();
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockThread);
  }
```

Is it possible to skip the mock interactions uncounted within log message, as it was in Mockito 4.x.x ?

Comment: `mockThread.getName()` returns `null`, not "org.slf4j.Logger". You call two methods on your mock: `start()` and `getName()`, but you only verify one. I'd expect the code as shown to fail. (But what is this test really testing? Nothing much, it only uses mocks and doesn't test any real behavior)

Comment: I just showed an example.   But there are similar cases where old mockito was rot recording the interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the reason for Mockito 4 skipping the mock interactions has nothing to do with logging. In fact, when you run this line:

```
logger.info("name ={}", mockThread.getName() );   //org.slf4j.Logger
```

you are not calling `mockThread.getName()` from your log method. You are in fact calling it directly from your test method, getting the resulting string and passing it to the log method.

A test using Mockito 4 passes even the following:

```
@Test
void name() {
    Thread mockThread = Mockito.mock(Thread.class);
    String x = mockThread.getName();
    mockThread.start();

    Mockito.verify(mockThread).start();
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockThread);
}
```

The reason seems to be that Mockito 4, for some strange reason, doesn't register `Thread.getName()` as an invocation. This seems like a bug or unintuitive behaviour, and I would recommend upgrading to Mockito 5 and adding

```
Mockito.verify(mockThread).getName();
```

before `verifyNoMoreInteractions` to make your test pass.

Comment: Yeah, probably a bug with Mockito.